# JasperGold error ECK025 Invalid clock declaration

Tags: system-verilog

I am working in JasperGold to verify a System Verilog design that I found online to use for class. When loading the .tcl file into JasperGold I recieve this error: "ERROR (ECK025): Invalid clock declaration: "clk". Clock definition must be on an input or environmental stopat." It also says "ERROR at line 12 in file /home/daileymn/Documents/Processor/test.tcl, more info in Tcl-variable errorInfo" I'm not really certain what this error means or how to fix it.

I tried looking it up in the JasperGold manual but could not find it.

Here is my system verilog code:

```
module testbench(input clk,input reset);

reg clk;
reg reset;
wire [7:0] result,OUT1,OUT2,Data2,mux1out,immediate,mux2out;
wire [2:0] Select;

initial
     $monitor("Res=%b O1=%b O2=%b D2=%b mux1=%b imm=%b mux2=%b S=%b clk=%b R=%b",result,OUT1,OUT2,Data2,mux1out,immediate,mux2out,Select,clk,reset);

proccessor myproccessor(result,OUT1,OUT2,Data2,mux1out,immediate,mux2out,Select,clk,reset);

initial
begin
    clk=1'b1;
    reset=0;
end

always #5 clk=~clk;

initial
begin
    #80 $finish;
end
endmodule

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module alu(out,Data1,Data2,Select);
input [7:0] Data1,Data2;
input [2:0] Select;
output reg [7:0] out;

always@(Data1,Data2,Select)
begin
case(Select)
3'b000:out<=Data1;
3'b001:out<=Data1+Data2;
3'b010:out<=Data1&Data2;
3'b011:out<=Data1|Data2;
endcase
end
endmodule

module regfile8x8a(OUT1,OUT2,clk,INaddr,OUT1addr,OUT2addr,IN);

input clk;
input [7:0] IN;
output [7:0] OUT1,OUT2;
input [2:0] INaddr,OUT1addr,OUT2addr;
reg [7:0] reg0, reg1, reg2, reg3,reg4,reg5,reg6,reg7;

assign OUT1 = (OUT1addr==3'b000)?reg0:
(OUT1addr==3'b001)?reg1:
(OUT1addr==3'b010)?reg2:
(OUT1addr==3'b011)?reg3:
(OUT1addr==3'b100)?reg4:
(OUT1addr==3'b101)?reg5:
(OUT1addr==3'b110)?reg6:
(OUT1addr==3'b111)?reg7:0;
// add until 8 //
assign OUT2 = OUT2addr == 0 ? reg0 :
OUT2addr == 1 ? reg1 :
OUT2addr == 2 ? reg2 :
OUT2addr == 3 ? reg3 :
OUT2addr == 4 ? reg4 :
OUT2addr == 5 ? reg5 :
OUT2addr == 6 ? reg6 :
OUT2addr == 7 ? reg7 :0;
//add until 8//
always @(negedge clk) 
begin
case(INaddr)
3'b000:reg0=IN;
3'b001:reg1=IN;
3'b010:reg2=IN;
3'b011:reg3=IN;
3'b100:reg4=IN;
3'b101:reg5=IN;
3'b110:reg6=IN;
3'b111:reg7=IN;
// your code here
endcase
end // always @ (negedgeclk)
endmodule

module CU(OUT1addr,OUT2addr,INaddr,immediate,Select,imm_signal,comp_signal,instruction);

input [31:0] instruction;
output reg [7:0] immediate;
output reg imm_signal;
output reg [2:0] Select;
output reg [2:0] OUT1addr;
output reg [2:0] OUT2addr;
output reg [2:0] INaddr;
output reg comp_signal;
always @(instruction) 
begin
    immediate = instruction[7:0];
    //opcode=instruction[31:24];
    Select = instruction[26:24];
    INaddr = instruction[18:16];
    OUT2addr = instruction[2:0];
    OUT1addr = instruction[10:8];
    imm_signal = 1'b0;
    comp_signal = 1'b0;
    case (instruction[31:24])
        8'b00001000:
            imm_signal = 1'b1;
        8'b00001001:                        
            comp_signal = 1'b1;
        default:;
    endcase
end
endmodule

module mux(out,select,input1,input2,clk);

input select,clk;
input [7:0] input1,input2;
output reg [7:0] out;
always @* begin
    if (select==1) 
        out = input1;
    else 
        out = input2;
end

endmodule

module compliment(out,in);
input [7:0] in;
output [7:0] out;
reg [7:0] comp=8'b11111111;
assign out=(comp-in)+8'b00000001;
endmodule

module regInstructions(instruction,clk,Read_Addr);
input clk;
input [2:0] Read_Addr;
output reg [31:0] instruction;

reg [31:0] addr1 = 32'b00001000000001000000000011111111;        // loadi 4, X, 0xFF
reg [31:0] addr2 = 32'b00001000000001100000000010101010;        // loadi 6, X, 0xAA
reg [31:0] addr3 = 32'b00001000000000110000000010111011;        // loadi 3, X, 0xBB
reg [31:0] addr4 = 32'b00000001000001010000011000000011;        // add   5, 6, 3
reg [31:0] addr5 = 32'b00000010000000010000010000000101;        // and   1, 4, 5
reg [31:0] addr6 = 32'b00000011000000100000000100000110;        // or    2, 1, 6 
reg [31:0] addr7 = 32'b00000000000001110000000000000010;        // mov   7, x, 2
reg [31:0] addr8 = 32'b00001001000001000000011100000011;        // sub   4, 7, 3

always @(negedge clk) 
begin
    case (Read_Addr)
        3'd0:instruction = addr1;
        3'd1:instruction = addr2;
        3'd2:instruction = addr3;
        3'd3:instruction = addr4;
        3'd4:instruction = addr5;
        3'd5:instruction = addr6;
        3'd6:instruction = addr7;
        3'd7:instruction = addr8;
        default :;
    endcase
end
endmodule

module counter (Read_addr,clk,reset);
input clk;
input reset;
output reg [2:0] Read_addr=0;
always @(negedge clk)
if(!reset) 
begin
    Read_addr<=Read_addr+3'd001;
end
else 
begin
    Read_addr<=0;   
end
endmodule

module proccessor(result,OUT1,OUT2,Data2,mux1out,immediate,mux2out,Select,clk,reset);
input reset;
input clk;
output [2:0] Select;
wire [2:0] Read_addr;
wire [31:0] instruction;
wire [2:0] OUT1addr,OUT2addr,INaddr;
output [7:0] immediate,OUT2,Data2,mux1out,result,OUT1,mux2out;
wire comp_signal,imm_signal;

counter mycounter(Read_addr,clk,reset);
regInstructions myreg(instruction,clk,Read_addr);
CU mycu(OUT1addr,OUT2addr,INaddr,immediate,Select,imm_signal,comp_signal,instruction);
regfile8x8a myregister(OUT1,OUT2,clk,INaddr,OUT1addr,OUT2addr,result);
compliment mycomp(Data2,OUT2);
mux mux1(mux1out,comp_signal,Data2,OUT2,clk);
mux mux2(mux2out,imm_signal,immediate,mux1out,clk);
alu myalu(result,mux2out,OUT1,Select);
regfile8x8a myregister1(OUT1,OUT2,clk,INaddr,OUT1addr,OUT2addr,result);
endmodule
```

And here is my .tcl code:

```
# Clear all previous designs
clear -all

# Analyze design file and specification file
analyze -sv09 processor.sv
#analyze -sv09  counter_assertion.sv

# Elaborate design
elaborate -sv09_expression_mode -top testbench -disable_auto_bbox

# Specify reset and clock pins
clock clk
reset reset
```

Answer (score 0):

Jasper needs the clock signal to be undriven inside the design -- in your case, there is an always block that controls it. You can either comment out the "always #5 clk=~clk;" line, or use the stopat command (something like "stopat -env clk" in your tcl, before the clock declaration).